# Как записать Location в переменную, при 302 статус коде?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Использую класс на volley следующего вида:

```
public StringPostRequest(Context context, String url, Map<String, String> params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.url = url;
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new NukeSSLCerts());
    }

public void getString(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url ,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    req = response;
                    callback.onSuccess(req);

                }
            }
            ,new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(final VolleyError error){
                final int status = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                // Handle 30x
                if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM == status || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
                    final String location = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");
                    callback.onSuccess(location);

                }
            }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return params;
        }
    };
    mQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String req);
}
```

В MainActivity собираю Map - параметры которые отправляю на сервер и посылаю запрос.

```
 Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("foo", "bar");
    params.put("foo1", "bar1");
    params.put("foo2", "bar2");

    StringPostRequest getRedirectUrl = new StringPostRequest(this,url,params);
    getRedirectUrl .getString(new StringPostRequest.VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String req) {
            Log.d("reqInMainact", req);
            RedirectUrl[0] = req;
        }
    });
    return RedirectUrl[0];
```

При получении определенной комбинации параметров, сервер присылает в header status code 302 и Location:https://foobar.ru?action=pay &transaction. 
Этот location не могу получить.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте кастомный `Request` (например, на основе `StringRequest`) и в `parseNetworkResponse` получайте заголовок и возвращайте его

```
public class LocationRequest extends StringRequest {

    public LocationRequest(int method, String url, String strRequest, Response.Listener
            <String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, strRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }

    public MetaRequest(String url, String strRequest, Response.Listener<String>
            listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(url, strRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        return response.headers.get("Location");
    }
}
```

Заголовок с `Location` придет в `onResponse`

```
String url = "http://...";
        Response.Listener<String> responseSuccess = new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                Log.d("#location", "Location of " + url + " -> " + response);
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener responseFailed = new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

            }
        };

        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, responseSuccess, responseFailed);
App.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Простите, но сделал проще )) Сразу открываю в WebView тот сайт от которого хотел получить Location, далее меня редиректит куда было нужно